# Ubuntu 18 Autocomplete Bug? "bash: cd: too many arguments"

Tags: testing, autocomplete, gnu-coreutils

Autocomplete started working bad after upgrading from ubuntu 16. If I hit tab after

```
git checkout src/
```

I get something like this:

```
$ git checkout src/bash: cd: too many arguments

main/ test/
```

Coincidentally I happened to see the same using the "test" command of gnu-coreutils:

```
$ ls
pom.xml  src  target
$ test pom.xml
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

Are the two things maybe connected? Unfortunately I couldn't find any bug after googling it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. One of my aliases had the name `test`, `lib` or `root` (I don't remember which one) and it was a `cd` command to a folder. Renaming the alias solved the problem for me.

Comment: I just spent the past 4 hours trying to debug why this was happening to me, and you hit the nail on the head. Made my day, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

My latest alias with .bashrc was with using words like test and git where I was  trying to change to corresponding directories. I have changed them to testdir and gitdir and restarted my computer. I don't have this `-bash: cd: too many arguments` error showing up now.